# como hacer if-elseif-else personalizado con helpers de handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

se como hacer un helper personalizasdo llamadao #isAdmin que verifica de mi lista de usuarios el que tenga el rol de ADMIN, y en base a eso me muestra button para borrar usuarios etc, pero no sabria como hacer un if else if else con helper ya que solo tengo fn y inverse. quiero que si es admin me salga un badge, si es TA otro y DEV otro

```js
HBS ===>

<h1>{{title}}</h1> 
<h3>{{usuarios}}</h3>
<ul class="list-group">
    {{#each users as |user|}}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        {{user.username}} 

        <a href="/users/{{user.id}}">see profile</a>
         {{#isAdmin user}} 
            <span class="badge badge-danger">ADMIN</span>
            {{#elseif isTA user}}
            <span class="badge badge-primary">TA</span>
            {{else}}
            <span class="badge badge-primary">DEV</span>
         {{/isAdmin}}

         {{!-- passportSession esta fuera de este scope del loop --}}
         {{#isAdmin ../passportSession}} 
         <form action="/users/{{user._id}}/delete" method="POST">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger float-right">x</button>
         </form>
         {{/isAdmin}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>

===> HELPER FOR HBS

const constants = require('../constants');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

module.exports = (hbs) => {

    hbs.registerHelper('json', function(context){
        return JSON.stringify(context);
    });

    hbs.registerHelper('isAdmin', (context, options) =>{
        if (context.role === constants.BOSS) {
            return options.fn(this);
        } else{
            return options.inverse(this);
        }
    });

    hbs.registerHelper('isTA', (context, options) =>{
        if (context.role === constants.TA) {
            return options.fn(this);
        } else{
            return options.inverse(this);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Hola Francisco. Por favor explica de tu problema , lo que has intentado (es parte del codigo que adjuntas?), qué errores o problemas concretos has tenido y cual es el resultado esperado y con qué datos podemos probarlo. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: he hecho un helper de hbs que comprueba si de todos los users listados, el que tenga el role de mi modelo de mongoose ADMIN, le salga un badge de ADMIN, se hacer eso y si es lo contrario le sale badge de DEV pero tambien tengo role de TA, pero en mi helper solo tengo un if y un else, porque asi nos lo han enseñado (if con la funcion fn y el else con la funcion inverse) pero no se como hacer si tiene el ROL de TA, hacer un else if en mi helper. nose si me explico bien =(

Comment: explicalo en la pregunta, pulsando en [edit].